# ListView is pushing up when keyboard popups

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

[This is without keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYw0I.png)

[This is with keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkxjN.png)

I hope you understood problem with image. This program is about custom adapter with listview.

This is mainactivity xml.

```
    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.athis.practiceproject1.MainActivity">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="440dp"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:divider="#1affffff"
            android:dividerHeight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">
        </ListView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/filter_button"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/filter"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sort_button"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/filter_button"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/filter_button"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/sort"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/search_button"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sort_button"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="8"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:hint="Search by Name"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/sort_button"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sort_button"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/search_button"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/search_button" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

This is mainactivity code

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ListView mListView;
List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>();
String[] mTitle = {"Robot Machine Project","Cold Coffee Maker","Game Creator"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    for(int i=0; i<=2; i++){
        Project project = new Project();
        project.setMtitle(mTitle[i]);
        project.setmPleadges("Pleadge - $80000");
        project.setmBackers("Backers - 1500");
        project.setmNoDays("No. of Days to go - 21");
        projects.add(project);
    }

    ProjectAdapter projectAdapter = new ProjectAdapter(MainActivity.this,projects);
    mListView.setAdapter(projectAdapter);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("title",mTitle[position]);
            intent.putExtra("pleadges","Pleadge - $80000");
            intent.putExtra("backers","Backers - 1500");
            intent.putExtra("days","No. of Days to go - 21");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    Button mFilterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.filter_button);
    mFilterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this,v);
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.filter_menu);
            popupMenu.show();

        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi the problem is in your layout:

I added `android:layout_below="@+id/filter_button"` in your XML under the list tag

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.athis.practiceproject1.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="440dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/filter_button"
        android:divider="#1affffff"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"></ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/filter_button"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/filter" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sort_button"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/filter_button"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/filter_button"
        android:background="@drawable/sort" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sort_button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/sort_button"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sort_button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/search_button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/search_button"
        android:ems="8"
        android:hint="Search by Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was bugging me for long time.